# addr2line can't get the function names from addresses that generated by the program built by clang

Tags: android, gcc, makefile, clang, android-source

I wanted to generate the calling graph with dot language for Android cmd "fastboot". The reference solution is at [IBM network](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/linux/l-graphvis/index.html)
But I can't get the function name from the function address. And I have added compiling parameters: "-g -finstrument-functions". After my investigations, I found that the latest aosp (6.0) used clang to build the host executable. So
I think the "-finstrument-functions" option in clang may have problems, and I always get the wrong function address, adddr2line also can't get the function name from the generated addresses, anybody give me some hints to tackle the issue. Thanks a lot.